# Dynamically recalculating row height of multiple tables after dragular drop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dragular

I want to drag an item from a list of items and drop it in a table column. Each columns of the table contains another sub table with a specific template.
I am using dragular for this.

Problem : As I render the view for the first time, I am calculating the height of each row in the sub table and making all the tables row height the same. So the final view looks like its all in one table.

Challenge Facing : When I drop a new item into the table columns (as another sub column) , I want to match the height of all the corresponding rows again in the sub tables. Not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please provide reproduced environment in some public link, like jfiddle for example? Because it is difficult to get clear picture of your problem. You can fork this example to start more easily http://jsfiddle.net/luckylooke/afv234uh/4/, thanks ;)

Comment: Thank you for your response. My base question was how to invoke a function on dropping. I was able to do it by invoking the function in a $timeout in the dragularDrop.